# VPS Linux more Minecraft server with different Java version

Tags: java, linux, debian, minecraft

How can I start 2 Minecraft servers using 2 different Java versions?

One server needs to run on Java 7 and the second server needs to run on Java 8.

How can I specify the version of Java to run each server with?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just the commands? `java7 minecraftserver.jar &; java8 minecraftserver.jar &;`

Comment: This is an off-topic question, it has nothing to do with programming: [on-topic questions on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)